# Anyone have any ideas why this tiny code snippet throws a COM exception?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

```
System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriLocation.LocatorManager"));
ILocatorManager2 locatorManager2 = obj as ILocatorManager2;
ILocatorWorkspace locatorWorkspace = locatorManager2.GetLocatorWorkspaceFromPath(@"Z:\ESRI\DataMaps10\streetmap_na");
locator = locatorWorkspace.GetLocator("Street_Addresses_US");
IAddressGeocoding addressGeocoding = (IAddressGeocoding)locator;  //this  fails
```

Inspecting the addressCoding object gives

'addressGeoCoding.matchFields' threw an exception of type Interop.COMException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My .loc file was corrupted

Answer (score 1):

check if the locator object is of the type IAddressGeocoding before casting it to that interface.

```
If(locator is IAdressGeocoding)
{
   IAddressGeocoding addressGeocoding = (IAddressGeocoding)locator;
}
```

Comment: surprisingly enough it is...

Comment: @iterationx, Noticed that the locator is not declared in the code snippet, how is it declared? I had som issues with some objects that got garbaged collected, setting the variable as static or as a class variable solved that..

Comment: I checked its not out of scope, I'll keep that in mind tho, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With ArcEngine, you need to be sure to call IAoInitialize.Initialize when your app starts.  Otherwise it throws exceptions in really strange places.

Comment: furthermore, at 10.0, you also need to Bind to a runtime before you  call Initialize (there's a helper method to both at once) http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/07/19/Bind-and-License-your-standalone-ArcGIS-Engine-or-Desktop-application.aspx